# Filling nan if row in another column meets condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null

I have the following dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'state':['AL','WI','FL','NJ','BM'],'country':['USA','USA','','','']})
```

I am trying to fill in my country column as 'USA' if the corresponding state row is following state list:

```
states = ['AL', 'WI', 'AZ', 'FL', 'NJ', 'CO', 'CT', 'NY']
```

I reviewed the following related SO post:
[Python Dataframe filling NaN values using information from other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980743/python-dataframe-filling-nan-values-using-information-from-other-columns)

Thought the question is similar, I am unable to use the apply function to my case since I don't know how to check if another column value is in a list of values. I tried the following (unsuccessful) code:

```
 df['country'] = values.where(df['country'] == np.nan and df['state'] in states, others=df['country'])
    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: `NaN` [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN) cannot be equal to anything, including itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumung the spaces are `np.nan` , if not, you can replace then by `df=df.replace('',np.nan)` you can use [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for faster results:

```
df.country=np.where(df.state.isin(states),df.country.fillna('USA'),df.country)
print(df)

  state country
0    AL     USA
1    WI     USA
2    FL     USA
3    NJ     USA
4    BM     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly. In my actual data I just had blanks in my country. So I had to fill in the missing data with df.country = df.country.replace('', np.NaN) before using your code.